# Changing websphere admin console interface color

Tags: console, websphere, environment, production, appserver

Is there any way to differentiate the WebSphere admin console interface of production environment from other environments? Recently one of our team member recycled the production server accidentally through WebSphere admin console. We want to have a thick red bar on top of production admin console or change the interface color of production admin console.

Answer (score 3):

The two ways:

- supported - you can `'name'` the given console via `System administration > Console identity` - you can provide a name which will appear in the top banner just after `Welcome adminUsername` text.
- unsupported - you can modify something (image, css) in the admin application, for example top banner image called `banner-swoosh.png` located in `C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\systemApps\isclite.ear\isclite.war\images` - remember to clear browser cache to see modifications, and that ***it will be replaced by any fixpack you will apply***.

Comment: Hi Gas, Thanks a lot for your answer. hope it will help me.

Comment: @Kumar If it will help/solve your issue remember to upvote/accept :). As you didn't provide WebSphere version, I assumed v8.5 for older versions banner image might have different name.

Comment: It is now possible to configure the background colour of the navigation. Go to System administration -> Console identity.  Documentation is here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/uisc_consoleid.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Gas suggests, another option might be to use a browser plugin like [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) for Firefox/Chrome to apply a custom style for each environment.

Here's a simple Stylish script that will make part of the banner use the specified background color:

```css
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document regexp("https://your-server:9043/ibm/console/.*") {
  #ibm-banner-main {
    background-color: green !important;
  }
}
```

Replace 'your-server' and potentially the 'https' and port, as appropriate.

You can list multiple `@-moz-document` sections too if you want a single script for different environments (Development, Test, Production, etc.)